# Formula to calculate sum of $k^k $ upto $n$ terms.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

What will be the general formula for the series: $1^1 + 2^2 + 3^3 + 4^4\ldots$

The series diverges, but can we have a formula to find the sum of $n$ terms.

Comment: There is no known general formula.

Comment: It's: $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty} n^n=+\infty$

Comment: I do understand that the series diverges, but can we get a formula to calculate the sum?

Comment: @Mohamed The title suggests finite sum, but the question and tags suggestion infinite sum.  Please clarify.

Comment: @iSimple Art: Thank's. I was attracted by dots.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function $f(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n k^k$ is called the hypertriangular function. There are some papers on it, for example

Mohammad K. Azarian, On the hyperfactorial function, hypertriangular function and the discriminants of certain polynomials. Int. J. Pure Appl. Math. 36 (2007), 251-257.

There some estimates are shown, like
$$
n^n\frac{4n-3}{4n-4}<1^1+2^2+3^3+\cdots +n^n<n^n\frac{2+e(n-1)}{e(n-1)}
$$
for all $n>1$.

The problem to find a formula is a problem by G.W. Wishard, posed in $1945$, see [here](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2306261?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents).

Comment: Hint, better bounds by using the fact that $f(n)\in\mathbb N$